# Forgot my Passphrase for git

Tags: github

I tried to commit for a new project that I have created, but it asks for the passphrase after I enter the command: `git push -u origin master`.
I don't remember what passphrase I had entered while setting up the account. 
I have access to the account through the git website.

Comment: Contact their help desk.

Answer (score 6):

Github doesn't have passphrases. ssh has passphrases. The passphrase you've forgotten is entirely local to your machine and associated with your personal private ssh key. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636071/131433 for a prescription.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new private key and then use that for committing. Also, make sure that the settings are correct in the 'Settings' section of your git client i.e. repository URL, user name and private key file etc.